# Can't get data from JSON parser android studio

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get a single data from a JSONParser List in android studio. No error when compiling but it keeps on force closed on device. Here is my JSONParser code:

```
public class JSONParser {
// Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    JSONArray jCountries = null;
    try {
        // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array
        jCountries = jObject.getJSONArray("konten");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
    // where each json object represent a country
    return getCountries(jCountries);
}


private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getCountries(JSONArray jCountries){
    int countryCount = jCountries.length();
    List<HashMap<String, Object>> countryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
    HashMap<String, Object> country = null;

    // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object
    for(int i=0; i<countryCount;i++){
        try {
            // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country
            country = getCountry((JSONObject)jCountries.get(i));
            countryList.add(country);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return countryList;
}

// Parsing the Country JSON object
private HashMap<String, Object> getCountry(JSONObject jCountry){

    HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    String idkos   = "";
    String namakos = "";
    String alamat  = "";
    String cp = "";
    String koordinat1 = "";
    String koordinat2 = "";
    String fasilitas  = "";
    String harga = "";
    String jenis = "";
    String foto1 = "";
    String foto2 = "";
    String foto3 = "";
    /*String countryName = "";
    String flag="";
    String language = "";
    String capital = "";
    String currencyCode = "";
    String currencyName = "";*/

    try {
        idkos   = jCountry.getString("id_kos");
        namakos = jCountry.getString("nama_kos");
        alamat  = jCountry.getString("alamat");
        cp = jCountry.getString("cp");
        koordinat1 = jCountry.getString("koordinat1");
        koordinat2 = jCountry.getString("koordinat2");
        fasilitas  = jCountry.getString("fasilitas");
        harga = jCountry.getString("harga");
        jenis = jCountry.getString("jenis");
        foto1 = jCountry.getString("foto1");
        foto2 = jCountry.getString("foto2");
        foto3 = jCountry.getString("foto3");

        country.put("id_kos", idkos);
        country.put("nama_kos", namakos);
        country.put("alamat", alamat);
        country.put("cp", cp);
        country.put("koordinat1", koordinat1);
        country.put("koordinat2", koordinat2);
        country.put("fasilitas", fasilitas);
        country.put("harga", harga);
        country.put("jenis", jenis);
        country.put("foto1", R.drawable.blank);
        country.put("foto2", foto2);
        country.put("foto3", foto3);
        country.put("id_kos", idkos);
        country.put("flag_path", foto1);



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return country;
}
}
```

And this is my activity code:

```
public class DisplayPeta extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG_SENTKAT = "exKategori";
private static final String TAG_SENTMIN = "exMin";
private static final String TAG_SENTMAX = "exMax";

ListView mListView;
// A list object to store the parsed countries list
List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_peta);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String exMin = in.getStringExtra(TAG_SENTMIN);
    String exMax = in.getStringExtra(TAG_SENTMAX);
    String exKat = in.getStringExtra(TAG_SENTKAT);

    // URL to the JSON data
    String strUrl = "http://smartkos.zz.mu/android/kos.php?min=" +exMin+ "&max=" +exMax+ "&jenis=" +exKat;
    //String strUrl = "http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/p/demo1/first.php/countries";

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Starting the download process
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

    // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_kos);

    // Set new Adapter from listView
    SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Click Listener + Intent DisplayInfo
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
            // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
            //LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

            // Getting the inner Linear Layout
            //LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

            // Getting the Country TextView
            //TextView nama = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);
            String nama = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.nama)).getText().toString();
            String idkos = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText().toString();
            String alamat = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.alamat)).getText().toString();
            String kontak = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.kontak)).getText().toString();
            String jenis = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.jenis)).getText().toString();
            String harga = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.harga)).getText().toString();
            String info = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.infotext)).getText().toString();
            String gal1 = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.gal1)).getText().toString();
            String gal2 = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.gal2)).getText().toString();
            String gal3 = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.gal3)).getText().toString();
            String lati = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.latitude)).getText().toString();
            String longi = ((TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.longitude)).getText().toString();
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), nama.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), nama, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Memulai memanggil ke class KontakActivity dengan data
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayInfo.class);
            in.putExtra("id", idkos);
            in.putExtra("nama", nama);
            in.putExtra("alamat", alamat);
            in.putExtra("kontak", kontak);
            in.putExtra("jenis", jenis);
            in.putExtra("harga", harga);
            in.putExtra("info", info);
            in.putExtra("gallery1", gal1);
            in.putExtra("gallery2", gal2);
            in.putExtra("gallery3", gal3);
            in.putExtra("lat", lati);
            in.putExtra("lon", longi);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    };
    // Setting the item click listener for the listview
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception download url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
    }

    return data;
}

/** AsyncTask to download json data */
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread
        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

        // Start parsing xml data
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);

    }
}

/** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{

    JSONObject jObject;
    // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {


        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
            jsonParser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
        }

        // Instantiating json parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        //List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;

        try{
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = jsonParser.parse(jObject);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }

        //NGELEBOKNE LATITUDE LONGITUDE NENG MAPS, COBA LEWAT KENE


        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "id_kos", "nama_kos", "flag", "harga" ,"alamat", "cp", "jenis", "fasilitas",
                "foto1", "foto2", "foto3", "koordinat1","koordinat2"};

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.id, R.id.nama,R.id.gambar,R.id.harga,R.id.alamat, R.id.kontak, R.id.jenis,
                R.id.infotext, R.id.gal1, R.id.gal2, R.id.gal3, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        return adapter;
    }


    // Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

        // Setting adapter for the listview
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("flag_path");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            hm.put("flag_path",imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);


            // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview
            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
        }
    }
}


// AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView
private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream=null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("flag_path");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Getting Caching directory
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

            //Close the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.close();

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("flag",tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position",position);

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
            return hmBitmap;


        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        // Getting the path to the downloaded image
        String path = (String) result.get("flag");

        // Getting the position of the downloaded image
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

        // Getting adapter of the listview
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

        // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);

        // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
        hm.put("flag",path);

        // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap(){
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    int jumlahdata= countries.size();
    for(int i=0;i<jumlahdata;i++){
        latitude = (double) countries.get(i).get("koordinat1");
        longitude = (double) countries.get(i).get("koordinat2");
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title("You are here!")
                .snippet("Consider yourself located"));
    }
}
}
```

It should display a map with some markers in it. It works fine without the countries.size and countries.get code, but when I add the size and get code, the application force closed on device. Can anyone help me?

Here is my logcat:

```
05-30 21:24:52.322  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist E/ResourceType﹕ 0x5ace6988: Failed to ResTable::remove() cookie = 0x3, not last table. mHeaders.size() = 4. Warning for spontaneous crashes when the garbage collector runs.
05-30 21:24:52.322  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist E/asset﹕ Error removing runtime skin resource (cookie 0x3)
05-30 21:24:52.322  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/asset﹕ Problem removing all runtime skin resources
05-30 21:24:52.602  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
05-30 21:24:52.612  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
05-30 21:24:52.622  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/libEGL﹕ loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
05-30 21:24:52.632  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.6.1.04.02.02.121.010_msm8960_JB_2.6_CL3869936_release_AU (CL3869936)
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
    Build Date: 11/16/13 Sat
    Local Branch:
    Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.6
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.6.1.04.02.02.121.010 +  NOTHING
05-30 21:24:52.732  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-30 21:25:06.136  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
05-30 21:25:06.146  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 120: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.checkPackage (ILjava/lang/String;)V
05-30 21:25:06.146  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
05-30 21:25:06.146  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzg
05-30 21:25:06.146  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 498: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
05-30 21:25:06.146  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
05-30 21:25:06.156  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/zzx﹕ Making Creator dynamically
05-30 21:25:06.226  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 7095000
05-30 21:25:06.246  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 7571034
05-30 21:25:06.277  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.AppOpsManager.checkPackage, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ij.a
05-30 21:25:06.277  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 111: Landroid/app/AppOpsManager;.checkPackage (ILjava/lang/String;)V
05-30 21:25:06.277  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0012
05-30 21:25:06.277  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ij.a
05-30 21:25:06.277  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 449: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
05-30 21:25:06.277  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000d
05-30 21:25:06.287  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setLocalOnly, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ij.b
05-30 21:25:06.287  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 154: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
05-30 21:25:06.287  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0201
05-30 21:25:06.947  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-30 21:25:06.947  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418ea8b0)
05-30 21:25:06.967  23664-23664/com.example.sk.maplist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sk.maplist/com.example.sk.maplist.DisplayPeta}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sk.maplist.DisplayPeta.setUpMap(DisplayPeta.java:400)
            at com.example.sk.maplist.DisplayPeta.setUpMapIfNeeded(DisplayPeta.java:385)
            at com.example.sk.maplist.DisplayPeta.onCreate(DisplayPeta.java:131)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the errors in your logcat.

Comment: @BidhanA edited :) here is my logcat

Comment: is your your mMap initialized? are you sure it's not null?

Comment: @TommySM yeah im sure it's not null. i do think it's the countries.size and countries.get problems. the json parser and map works fine without them.

Comment: more likely the .get(),  because.size() should usually throw another exception. try the good old printing method for each one, it's probably the quickest way to see which one is the problem. In general maybe you shoud look into using GSON, it's a very quick and solid JSON parser it might also be clearer to debug, and I would also switch to either Volley or Retrofit for your networking instead of AsyncTask and HttpUrlConnection, again, quicker, more reliable, and more widley used, look it up.

Comment: @TommySM i've tried getting .get and .size separately and both caused the app to force close. Well, I guess I will do some research first, thank you :)